# optimizing code running time [diffrence between the codes below]

Tags: python, python-3.x

these are two codes, can anyone tell me why the second one takes more time to run.

```
#1
ar = [9547948, 8558390, 9999933, 5148263, 5764559, 906438, 9296778, 1156268]
 count=0
 big = max(ar)
 for i in range(len(ar)):
    if(ar[i]==big):
        count+=1
 print(count)


#2
ar = [9547948, 8558390, 9999933, 5148263, 5764559, 906438, 9296778, 1156268]
list = [i for i in ar if i == max(ar)]
return len(list)
```

Comment: Because you recalculate `max(ar)` on each loop in the list comprehension. That makes your code run in O(n**2), too, so things will get worse when `ar` gets bigger.

Comment: `ar.count(max(ar))`

Comment: @Peter, that may well be a better way but it doesn't really answer the question as to why the second is slower than the first. But I guess that's why you made it a comment rather than an answer, so I'll shut up now :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo  You're right we should address OP's misunderstanding. There are better algorithms though. We are both using 2 linear searches when only one pass is really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In the list comprehension (the second one), the `if` clause is evaluated for each candidate item, so `max()` is evaluated each time.

In the first one, the maximum is evaluated *once,* before the loop starts. You could probably get a similar performance from the list comprehension by pre-evaluating the maximum in the same way:

```
maxiest = max(ar)
list = [i for i in ar if i == maxiest]
```

Additionally, you're not creating a new list in the first one, rather you're just counting the items that match the biggest one. That *may* also have an impact but you'd have to do some measurements to be certain.

---

Of course, if you just want to know what the difference between those two algorithms are, that hopefully answers your question. However, you should be aware that `max` itself will generally pass over the data, then your search will do that again. There *is* a way to do it with only *one* pass, something like:

```
def countLargest(collection):
    # Just return zero for empty list.

    if len(collection) == 0: return 0

    # Setup so first item is largest with count one.

    count = 0
    largest = collection[0]

    # Process every item.

    for item in collection:
        if item > largest:
            # Larger: Replace with count one.

            largest = item
            count = 1
        elif item == largest:
            # Equal: increase count.

            count += 1

    return count
```

Just keep in mind you should *check* if that's faster, based on likely data sets (the optimisation mantra is *"measure, don't guess"*).

And, to be honest, it won't make much difference until either your data sets get very large or you need to do it many, *many* times per second. It certainly won't make any real difference for your eight-element collection. Sometimes, it's better to optimise for readability rather than performance.

Comment: Is there anything else?